# Error indicator on role in cloud project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I recently updated a client project to use Azure SDK 2.1 from 1.8. (Storage Client was updated a while ago). This was done on a feature branch.

During this process one of the roles in the cloud project started showing an error indicator.

[image: role error indicator]

Since this time, I have abandoned that feature branch. My project is back on the 1.8 SDK (October 2012 according to the Application tab). But the error indicator is still there. Other team members do not see this error. I do not see an error described anywhere.

How do I clear this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not notice that the web project associated with this role had been unloaded. After reloading, the error indicator goes away. doh!

This did not show up when switching branches since loaded/unloaded is an .suo setting that is excluded from source control